# Dynamic Binding Java. Does an object have the methods of its declared type, or its actual type?

Tags: java, dynamic, binding

Say I declare the following:

```
Cat elsa = new Lion();
```

Lion extends Cat. If I declare it this way, will elsa be a cat having **All of the methods of a cat** or will it be a Lion, **having all of the methods of both lion and cat**

This exact question is not addressed in other questions that I could find.

Comment: Why don't you try and see ?

Comment: I tried and it seems to me as if it takes on the declared type. Is that right? I just want to make sure i'm not missing anything.

Comment: You're not missing anything, declaring elsa as a Cat restricts it only to methods that are implemented by Cat (but which can be overriden by Lion).

Comment: Assigning a `Lion` object to a `Cat` reference doesn't change what methods the object has (at run time).  It changes what methods the compiler will let you access (at compile time).  If all that mattered was that the object has the methods then java would have duck typing.  It doesn't.  You can hack your way around this problem by casting but just makes people wonder why you bothered making a `Cat` class in the first place.  The whole point of the `Cat` type was to say, "as long as you can do what a cat does you can go here and just be a `Cat`,  Nothing will ask you to do more then that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***object*** you create is of type `Lion` and has all of the attributes and methods of the `Lion` object.  The ***variable*** `elsa` however is of type `Cat` so it can only be used to access methods and attributes of a `Cat` object.

So the answer to your question is that `elsa` will be a `Lion` that you can only treat as a `Cat` unless you cast it back to a `Lion`.  For example:

```
elsa.roar();          // compile error if the roar() method is only for Lion
((Lion)elsa).roar();  // will work
```

Comment: Better design is `elsa.speak()` which may produce "Mew", "Roar!", or "What's happenin' baby?"